# preventing &amp;amp;pound; from being echoed: why doesn't the actual symbol show?

Tags: php, mysql

> VVTI COLOUR COLLECTION T3 61,107 MILES
>   3 Door Hatchback, Silver, Petrol,
>   Manual, Side airbags, Folding rear
>   seats, Trip computer, Front electric
>   windows, Front head restraints, Rear
>   wiper. PAS, Electric front windows, CD
>   player excellent condition and drives
>   very well. Very economical 6 MONTHS
>   TAX, 12 MONTHS MOT CAT C REPAIRED
>   &amp;pound;2100 NO OFFERS.
>   &amp;pound;2100 No offers

Whenever I try to echo any data from my MySQL database, I can't get any symbols to display. How do I resolve this problem?

Comment: see the example in given [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like all applicable characters have been converted to html entities twice.

You have `&amp;pound;` which when decoded is `&pound;` which when decoded is £

If you have the text as a variable `$text`, use [html_entity_decode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php):

echo html_entity_decode($text);

Or... If you were the one converting the characters twice... do it once! Its effectively like running [htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) twice on a string... then you'd have to use [html_entity_decode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) twice to get it back.

Comment: $this->car_features = stripslashes(html_entity_decode($rows['features']));

Answer (score 0):

Use [htmlspecialchars_decode(string)](http://pl.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php) to decode your mysql string with symbols intact.

More explanation: it appears when your string is stored [htmlspecialchars()](http://pl.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) is being used (as it should be) to encode html sensitive data.